# How to redirect homepage to subfolder without changing URL (still keep www.example.com)

Tags: php, .htaccess

My current `.htaccess` is in httpdocs.
How can I configure it to help domain point to subfolder is `/vn/`

and still keep: `www.example.com` instead of `www.example.com/vn/`

Comment: Can't you just update the document root in your apache config to point to that folder instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /vn/$1 [L]
```

This *internally rewrites* all requests that hit the document root to the `/vn/` subdirectory. The `RewriteCond` directive that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures the request is only rewritten once - thus avoiding a rewrite loop.

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess add these lines :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^blog/ /blog%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Or in some hosts :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?YourDomainName.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog [L]
```